# Using String.compare inside a lambda expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

I have the following model method:

```
public IQueryable<CustomerVLAN> CustomerVLANS(int customerid)
    {
        string customername = entities.AccountDefinitions.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.ORG_ID == customerid).ORG_NAME;// .tolist since i will be querying different context

        return tms.CustomerVLANS.Where(String.Compare(a=>a.CustomerName.ToString(), customername.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

but I am unable to use the String.Compare inside my where clause ,,,

Answer (score 1):

The [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension filters an `IEnumerable` using a supplied predicate function: `Func<TSource, bool>`, in your case `Func<CustomerVLAN, bool>`.

Your line "`String.Compare(a=>a.CustomerName.ToString(), customername.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`" returns an integer, rather than a `Func<CustomerVLAN, bool>` delegate (I'm also not sure if there's an overload of string `Compare` which expects the values you've provided).

If you wanted to use that particular function, you'd have to do something like this (using a Lambda expression):

```
CustomerVLANS.Where(x => (String.Compare(x.CustomerName, customername, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0));
```

Unless there's a particular reason for it, you may well be better of using `String.Equals`, which returns a boolean:

```
CustomerVLANS.Where(x => (String.Equals(x.CustomerName, customername)));
```

You may need your `ToString()`, depending on what type CustomerName is.

Answer (score 0):

Provided CustomerName and customername are strings, you can try

```
return tms.CustomerVLANS.Where(a=>a.CustomerName.ToUpper() == customername.ToUpper());
```